# Using RegEx in Javascript to match similar strings that have characters swapped

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am using RegEx's to find the frequency of occurrences of certain string values in a large data set. This was working fine until I found some of the years worth of data have been entered with a typo, meaning two characters have been swapped around. It is not feasible to edit the data sets to correct the typo. Therefore, is it possible to define a RegEx that will match the strings regardless of the index of just two characters within them?

The strings in question are:

"gcse/o-level/cse" and "gsce/o-level/cse"

I am aware I can simply search by the characters found after the typo, but I would like to know if there is a RegEx method to deal with this sort of occurrence as I could not find any mention of a solution anywhere else, and thought it posed an interesting challenge.

Comment: Please post more examples of the  input and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
/g(cs|sc)e\/o-level\/cse/
```

`|` here means "or", as you're used to.

Comment: This is good.. but I thought OP was asking in general.. and it would be difficult.. i guess?

Comment: Hu ? OP, you mean you want to match in case of any two chars inverted ?

Comment: I must leave. I'll delete my answer tomorrow if it doesn't answer

Comment: Exactly, in case two characters were inverted it would match either case.
Your suggestion works fine so far, thanks